# HTML Table text into Crystal Report

Tags: html, crystal-reports

I'm building a Report with Crystal Report.
In this report I have a field with HTML text formatting. So if I try to insert a html tag as

```
<b> |<br/>
```

I don't have any problem, but if I try to insert a HTML table, I can't show it.

This is the code of HTML table

```
<b>EMOCROMOCITOMETRICO</b>
</br>eseguito in data 10-30-2017</br>ESITO: </br></br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th width="200px">Parametro</th>
        <th width="100px">Valore</th>
        <th width="50px">U.M.</th>
        <th width="100px">Valori di Riferimento</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="200px" style='border-bottom:1pt solid black;'>RBC</td>
        <td width="100px" style='border-bottom:1pt solid black;'>5.000</td>
        <td width="50px" style='border-bottom:1pt solid black;'>10*6/uL</td>
        <td width="100px" style='border-bottom:1pt solid black;' align="right">4.00 - 5.40   </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have insert a Field in Crystal Report, so right click on it, Format Object -> Paragraph -> Text Html on Interpretation text section.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the HTML tags supported within Crystal Reports is rather limited.  For example, the `<th>` tag isn't supported at all.  The `<tr>` tag is supported, but it ends up working more like a `<div>` tag and doesn't maintain a column structure for a table and only creates a paragraph break instead.

Some of the attributes you are trying to use are not supported as well.  Here is a link that lists what is supported.

https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1217084

You will need to use the other tools available in CR to build your table.